# Type="datatime-local" não pega os segundos

Tags: html5, java-ee, spring-mvc

A pouco tempo a W3C passou a descontinuar o "datatime" e usar "datatime-local", mas não consigo pegar mais os segundos para fazer um relatório específico. Amigos podem me ajudar?

Comment: <input type="datatime-local">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que setar o `setp` do `input` como **1**, tipo `step="1"`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja aqui uma lista, me parece que vc quer o último exemplo, repare que está com o `step="1"`. Tenha em mente que isso pode ter condições crossbrowser, podendo ser diferente dependendo do user-agente do browser do cliente

```html
<input type="time">  
<input type="time" step="1">  
<input type="date">  
<input type="datetime">  <!-- deprecado sem formatação do user-agent -->
<input type="datetime-local" step="1">
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte da imagem que foi retirado da documentação da Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-step